# Second fundamental form is symmetric

Tags: differential-geometry

Define the second fundamental form (taking a vector $X\in T_p(M)$ and a tangent vector field Y on a manifold $M$ to a normal vector field) $B(X,Y)=P_N(\partial_X Y)$, where $P_N$ is the projection operator from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $N_p(M)$ (the normal space at point $p$) and $\partial_X$ is the derivative along direction $X$ on the manifold $M$. By varing the point $p$ this extends to a bilinear form $B: T_p(M)\times T_p(M) \to N_p(M)$.  I am struggling with showing that, defined this way, this form is symmetric.

In the lecture I am currently watching the following plan is suggested:

1. Observe that $B(X,Y)-B(Y,X)=P_N(\partial_XY-\partial_YX)$.
2. Notice that $\partial_XY-\partial_YX=[X,Y]$ (commutator or bracket of vector fields).
3. Finally, notice that brackets of tangent vector fields are tangent vector fields.

I am stuck at step 2. As far as I understand, by definition $[X,Y]$ is a tangent vector field such that for all smooth functions $f$ $$\partial_{[X,Y]}f=\partial_X\partial_Y f-\partial_Y\partial_X f.$$

Now I have to show that this is actually exactly $\partial_{\partial_XY-\partial_Y X}f.$ And I have no idea how to begin.

Comment: Be specific about where your $M$ lives and how the covariant derivative $\partial_X$ is defined. The equation you're stuck on is what it means to say the connection is torsion-free.

Comment: I think there's no covariant derivate is involved here (explicitly). Your problem might be only notational. It's usual to write $Xf=\partial_Xf$, thus a vector (field) acts as a linear operator on the space of smooth functions. And the Lie bracket is defined exactly as $[X,Y] =XY-YX$..

Comment: @Berci I think you identified my problem. I do not understand what $XY$ means here. It seems one can interpret it both as $\partial_X Y$ and $\partial_X\circ\partial_Y$ and the result should be the same, but I don't get why.

Comment: The key point is that somehow a linear operator on the set of smooth functions which satisfies the Leibniz rule, corresponds to differentiation along a vector field. If $X, Y$ are such  operators, then $[X, Y]$ is also such, while $XY$ don't satisfy the Leibniz rule..